# Adapting SwiftUI like flow in UIKit/Storyboard based app

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uikit, storyboard

I have the following flow in a sample SwiftUI example which is very handy. It basically checks for a flag in `UserDefaults` whether an intro view has been shown before or not, and based on it loads the `ContentView` or `IntroView`. Once `IntroView` has been shown and the user taps the `IntroView`, it automatically switches back to `ContentView`. This is really a good feature in SwiftUI where the `App` struct observes the bool and recomputes `WindowGroup`.

**Problem**: I have an existing UIKit based app based on Storyboard and I am slowly injecting SwiftUI views into it using `UIHostingController`. But I don't really get SwiftUI app lifecycle benefits like above in it and it becomes cumbersome. For instance, after showing `IntroView`, I might need to show another view such as `PermissionsView` where I ask for camera and photo library permissions which the user can alter anytime in iOS Settings. In SwiftUI, the code such as below automatically watches any changes and pops the `IntroView` or `PermissionsView`. How do I do this in my `UIKit` based app? Is it possible to migrate the `UIApplicationDelegate` & `SceneDelegate` code to SwiftUI `App` while still having view controllers load from Storyboard?

```
@main
struct TestSwiftUIIntroViewsApp: App {

   @AppStorage("showedIntroView") var showedIntroView: Bool = false

   var body: some Scene {
      WindowGroup {
         if showedIntroView {
             ContentView()
         } else {
             IntroView()
         }
     }
   }
 }

struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text("Content View")
       }
       .padding()
   }
 }

struct IntroView: View {

    @AppStorage("showedIntroView") var showedIntroView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
      VStack(alignment: .center, content: {
         Text("Intro View")
      })
     .onTapGesture {
        showedIntroView = true
      }
    }
```

}

Comment: Yes it's possible to use the SwiftUI `App` with `UIViewController`s and Storyboards. All you need to do is wrap them in [`UIViewControllerRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable).

Comment: So I need to delete `AppDelegate` and `SceneDelegate`, make a SwiftUI `App` struct as entry point, instantiate a `WindowGroup`, and the load Storyboard based initial View controller in it? How does the process go?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm getting this right, but yes, you can load storyboard views or any UIViewController view doing something like this:

```
struct MyView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyViewController {
        // For Storyboard views
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
        // For manually created UIViewControllers
        /*
        let vc = MyAwesomeViewController()
        return vc
        */
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewController, context: Context) {
        // Update the view controller here
    }
}
```

Then you can use the above code like it was a SwiftUI view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}
```

Also, I don't know how old is your app but it seems pretty recent to me, but it was common practice to use AppDelegate (and even before SceneDelegate) in SwiftUI apps. If you want to use an AppDelegate or your existing one into your SwiftUI app you can by declaring it into the struct that conforms to App in your SwiftUI project like this:

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(MyAppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

And it should work like it was in a UIKit this way.
I hope I was able to at least help you partially.
Have a nice coding day!

Comment: App is pretty old. So I need to delete AppDelegate and SceneDelegate, make a SwiftUI App struct as entry point, instantiate a WindowGroup, and the load Storyboard based initial View controller in it? How does the process go?

Comment: At this point I would suggest you to start from scratch with a new project reusing files from your old project like storyboards and stuff using the way I showed you to use them like native SwiftUI views. But if you want to get rid of AppDelegate and SceneDelegate you can do it starting from the info.plist file, but it can be tedius depending on how many references there are to those files...

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: This [link](https://www.en.techgaku.com/migrate-lifecycle-of-ios-app-to-swiftuiapp-from-uikit/)  is suggesting to migrate to SwiftU lifecycle step by step.

Comment: 90% of that page you linked is stuff I told you above like the UIViewControllerRepresentable stuff and going through the info.plist.